# Why won't my companions react to the correct actions at all?

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4

When you take an action in front of a companion, that companion may like or dislike that action which affects your relationship with them. This is accompanied with a message stating something like "[xy liked that.]". Depending on the companion, they can react to actions such as stealing, entering Power Armour, Picking a lock etc, but recently whenever I performed any such actions, there was no pop up.

This issue has been present for two days, nor is occurring due to an affinity change cooldown.

- I have picked two locks in front of Piper in close time intervals, and neither such actions resulted in a popup.
- This is not caused by any cooldown, and occurs with any of my companions regardless of affinity status.
- Restarting my game and even my console DID NOT fix anything.

I have read the [Companion affinity change notification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248682/companion-affinity-change-notification) question however it is asking about the cooldown and doesn't address this bug.

I am playing Fallout 4 for the Xbox One. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: @pushasha .. I know of the cooldown, however this occurred at all points of the game, with both likes and dislikes. To test this, I murdered a non-hostile in front of a companion that hates it the minute I reloaded a save file, and no box popped up.

Comment: And this is happening with every single companion? Or just a few? Because there is this little tidbit on one of the Fallout wikis: "When affinity reaches 249, 499, 749, and 999, it will sometimes be temporarily frozen, while the companion in question will try to talk with the sole survivor. This could just be a simple chit-chat about how they appreciate you, or the start of a new quest. Occasionally the affinity will continue to be frozen until the corresponding quest has progressed sufficiently." If it is happening for all your companions, that sounds like a bug. Send BethSoft your save!

Comment: @pushasha Thank you!! And yes, I thought it was just Danse for a while, but I tried every one of my companions and still got no reaction, nor small chit-chat. I'll try just that. Again, thank you. uvu

Comment: If your only argument for reopening is that the other questions answers do not solve your problem, I'm afraid your out of luck. That doesn't disprove duplication, it just means the answers do not help you. Also, we do not acknowledge answers in valid argument for closure and reopening. I would suggest earning yourself some reputation and placing a bounty on the original question. You can request an alternate answer, and reward the bounty to whoever is able to solve your specific problem. You may not agree with it, but it is policy.

Comment: That other question specifically mentions cooldowns, and is about cooldowns. This one says right out that that's not the issue. Seems clear to me that it's not a duplicate, and also clear that they've done their research and checked the other answer and its solutions. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @DCShannon Thank you. This is exactly what I have been trying to say without being rude. uvu

Answer (score 1):

The scripting engine for Fallout 4 is a right pain, and this shows more than anything with companions now that the dreaded "cell reset bug" is dead.  Things that can go wrong include:

- All notifications become hidden and won't appear until you restart the game
- Companion scripts start to fire off and then are interrupted by another process (such as a sudden ambush).  The game flags the conversation as complete but doesn't actually progress the associated quest. Sometimes this cleans up if you dismiss the companion and journey around for awhile without them.
- A mod can chuck a wrench in your save due to cell or character state issues being in conflict
- Some of the world managing scripts like the ones that manage your settlements and companions can get stuck waiting on something.  You'd think they have priority, but patches have messed with this a bit.  One of the worst was when Bethesda patched settlements to only load any villager information when you're in them and made settlement attacks a diceroll, effectively making your defenses moot as far as placement.  What this did to settlement mods was tragic.
- Yet more fun "features".

It sounds like all of your companions have hit the settler script, which isn't good.  That's a thing that can happen if a companion breaks, and happens to Danse most often due to his changing factions during the game.  It starts like this, then eventually they only take settler commands when you see them in settlements and won't follow you anymore.  If you have installed a mod that overhauls the AI for companions, this can be the cause.  Unfortunately, restoring an earlier save is usually the fix.  On PC, sometimes the "resurrect" command fixes it, but that doesn't do you any good.

Comment: Patches screwed stuff up, eh? You don't say...  ;p - Good to know. I'll keep rocking my ancient version. Are any of those patches prior to the new hard mode? (That's the last time I updated)